# How to write a function that takes a list and a value as parameters and returns the index of the first occurring value?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function called `find`, which takes a list and a value as parameters. The code should search through the list to find the value and return back its index that it is in the list.

Here some code that I managed to do. It's almost correct but the 2 should be a 3.

```
def find(my_list, value):
    index = 0
    for element in my_list:
        if element == value:
            index += 1
    return index
```

The list is

```
['r','i','n','g','i','n','g']
```

Comment: Can you not use the lists `.index()` method?

Comment: You are increasing the `index` when the element is found, while you should do it the other way around. Always increase it, and `return` as soon as it is found.

Answer (score 0):

there's a built in method that does exactly this:

`my_list.index(value)` will output the index of the value

if you are bent on making your own, make this modification:

```
def find(my_list, value):
    index = 0
    for element in my_list:
        if element == value:
            return index
        else:
            index+=1
```

Comment: Derek Eden - So, I have gotten it to return the index 3 for the value 'g', but what if I wanted to return the index of a value that isn't in the list, lets say a 'z' for example.

Comment: currently it will return nothing, but if you want to handle that case, you can also add an if statement before the loop saying if value not in my_list: return None or some error

Answer (score 0):

```py
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'i', 'u']

# element 'i' is searched
index = vowels.index('i')

# only the first index of the element is printed
print('The index of i:', index)
```

#### Output:

`The index of i: 2`

Answer (score 0):

Use enumerate ()

```py
def find(my_list, value):
    for index,element in enumerate (my_list):
        if element == value:
            break
    return index
```

Edit:

```py
def find(my_list, value):
    for index,element in enumerate (my_list):
        if element == value:
            return index
```

Comment: Why `break` when you can just return at that point and end both the loop and the function?

Comment: Nice observation. I just typed it hastly down. I edit it accordingly.